# CSS / HTML Yellow box does not appear

Tags: html, css

I just started to learn CSS/HTML, trying to build my firt website. Now I'm stuck with news box.

What I've created: http://jsfiddle.net/cvk5a3nn/2/

The problem: Yellow box(`.news`) does not appear around `.news h1`

Comment: Change your `news` tag into a div and it will work fine.

Comment: It worked. Can you explain me why is that? Because I have `<header></header>` tags and It works perfect.

Comment: `Header` is valid HTML markup, News (as to my knowledge) is not. [Here's a list](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_new_elements.asp)

Comment: Hello, it worked. But why does    `text-decoration-color:white;` not work. Text in `h1` tags is still black.

Comment: `text-decoration-color` isn't correct.  You should just be using `color` instead to change the text color.

Comment: Example: `color: white;`

Answer (score 0):

Well, If I'm understanding your question correctly, the solution is easy.

Add a `display:inline-block` to the `.news` element.

A jsFiddle with it....

http://jsfiddle.net/cvk5a3nn/3/

Hope it's what you're looking for.

Regards

Comment: Hello, it worked. But why does    `text-decoration-color:white;` not work. Text in `h1` tags is still black.

Comment: That happens because the css rule is not: `text-decoration-color`..... The appropiate rule is just "`color`"..... replace it with: `color:white;`

Answer (score 0):

The point in not if  is a valid HTML element 'cause, about user defined elements (like this one), the brouser should be "neutral" and apply anyway the user defined rules; the point is correctly defining rules of the custom elements, as edd2110 showed...

Answer (score -1):

The `news` tag you used to wrap your `h1` tag is not valid HTML/HTML5 markup. Instead, use either a `div`, `article`, `section`, or [any of the tags listed here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp)

Comment: Hello, it worked. But why does    `text-decoration-color:white;` not work. Text in `h1` tags is still black.

Comment: Use `color` not `text-decoration-color`